# Do Organizational culture and social power bases interact to determine follower outcomes or should I study a moderation effect?

Tags: interaction

I am writing my dissertation on the "Effects of Social Power Bases within Varying Organizational Culture."  I keep writing that I am looking at how organizational culture and social power bases will interact to determine follower outcomes of compliance and commitment.  However, I am confused as to whether I should actually be studying whether organizational culture is a moderator of the relationship between the power bases and the follower outcomes, which relationships have been widely studied in the literature.  Any advice you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While this is phrased in a way that looks like it's asking for an opinion about what you should study (which would be opinion based and thereby off-topic), at heart this turns out to be a question about explaining the connection between moderators and interaction - which is on-topic. [It would be useful if you could edit your question in a way that didn't appear to be calling for opinion on what you should study, but instead more directly asked a question about statistical issues.]

Answer (score 0):

The statements

"$A$ is a moderator of the relationship between $B$ and $y$"

and

"There's an interaction between $A$ and $B$ in their relationship with $y$"

are effectively synonymous.

For example, see the second sentence in the Wikipedia article on [moderation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderation_%28statistics%29):

> The effect of a moderating variable is characterized statistically as an interaction

The notion of *moderation* shouldn't be limited to simple linear interaction, but in practice that's almost always exactly how it's assessed.

So doing what you're doing is also *studying whether organizational culture is a moderator of the relationship between the power bases and the follower outcomes*.